# unable to view the modules

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm unable to view the modules when I enter to VBA in Outlook. It opens the window, but when I'm trying to view the code I had in module 1, it just doesn't open it. And also, when I try to insert a new module, Outlook crashes and it restarts the program. I can't delete modules as well. It seems like VBA for Outlook in my computer crashed.
Everything was fine, I had some macros I created to send specific emails, and the code was really simple. But now, of course it doesn´t run the code.

[image: Screenshot of the VBA window for Outlook]

I have Office 365 and VBA runs perfectly on other apps like Word, Excel, etc.

I tried to reinstall Office 365, but i still have the same problem. I tried to delete the modules where I had the code running, but I can't.

**UPDATE.-** I was able to open the module window where my code is. Can you tell me if somehow my code has something that corrupts Outlook, and I might have the same problem in the future?

```
Sub RETIRO_MAT_PLANTA()
    Dim MAIL As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim DIAH As String

' Crear un nuevo correo
Set MAIL = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
DIAH = Format(Date, "DDDD")

' Configurar propiedades del correo
With MAIL
    .Display
    .To = "example@example.com"
    .CC = "example@example.com
    .Subject = "Solicitud de retiro temporal de materiales de planta Piñami 1 - " & DIAH & " " & Date
    .HTMLBody = "<html><body>" & _
                "<p>Estimado,</p>" & _
                "<p>Le solicito autorización para que la empresa NOMBRE pueda retirar el siguiente material de planta 1, el día de hoy " & Date & " a su taller para realizar modificaciones. El material retornará el mismo día " & Date & ".</p>" & _
                "<ul>" & _
                "<li>Elemento 1 de la lista</li>" & _
                "<li>Elemento 2 de la lista</li>" & _
                "</ul>" & _
                "<p>Adjunto la foto de referencia. Le agradezco de antemano por la colaboración y quedo atento a sus comentarios.</p>" & _
                "</body></html>" & .HTMLBody
            
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems more likely to me that the outlook file you are loading has somehow corrupted itself so that the VBA modules in it no longer work. Do you have an older copy of the same file? Can you create a completely new outlook file and add a VBA module to it? Even better if you have saved a backup copy somewhere...

Comment: You might try an office repair to see if this corrects any corruptions.

Comment: @MartinBrown I believe that once it asked me to save the outlook.project but I'm not sure where it is located or the name it was saved with.

Comment: @freeflow how Can I run an office repair?

Comment: Its in the same location as reinstall.  Or you could google 'how to repair office 365'

Comment: It all looks pretty harmless to me. Have you tried copying the source code from the existing faulty module into a new clean one and start from scratch? If it will run OK elsewhere that suggest the fault is file corruption of some sort.